# Spark MLlib - SQLContext - Group items based on top 3 value

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib, market-basket-analysis

I'm trying to make some Basket Market Analysis using Spark MLlib with this dataset:

```
Purchase_ID Category    Furnisher   Value
1   ,   A   ,   1   ,   7
1   ,   B   ,   2   ,   7
2   ,   A   ,   1   ,   1
3   ,   C   ,   2   ,   4
3   ,   A   ,   1   ,   4
3   ,   D   ,   3   ,   4
4   ,   D   ,   3   ,   10
4   ,   A   ,   1   ,   10
5   ,   E   ,   1   ,   8
5   ,   B   ,   3   ,   8
5   ,   A   ,   1   ,   8
6   ,   A   ,   1   ,   3
6   ,   B   ,   1   ,   3
6   ,   C   ,   5   ,   3
7   ,   D   ,   3   ,   4
7   ,   A   ,   1   ,   4
```

The transaction value (value) is grouped by each Purchase_ID. And what I want is just return the top 3 categories ​​with higher Value. Basically, I want to return this dataset:

```
D,A
E,B,A
A,B
```

For that I'm trying with the following code:

```
val data = sc.textFile("PATH");

case class Transactions(Purchase_ID:String,Category:String,Furnisher:String,Value:String);

def csvToMyClass(line: String) = {
val split = line.split(',');
Transactions(split(0),split(1),split(2),split(3))}

val df = data.map(csvToMyClass)
        .toDF("Purchase_ID","Category","Furnisher","Value")
        .(select("Purchase_ID","Category") FROM (SELECT "Purchase_ID","Category",dense_rank() over (PARTITION BY "Category" ORDER BY "Value" DESC) as rank) tmp WHERE rank <= 3)
        .distinct();
```

The rank function isn't correct...

Anyone knows how to solve this problem?

Many thanks!

Comment: You can use RDD or you want to use Dataframe only??

Comment: Yes, I can use RDD

Comment: Will it work If i write code in java. You can convert same in scala very easily :P

Comment: How can use that statement in Scala? :)

Comment: I meant you can not use directly use but you can convert java to scala?? Because Spark Java and Scala are almost same.

Comment: I'm using Spark-Shell, is there a way to integrate Java code into my Spark Scala code?

Comment: I don't think so. 
Check https://acadgild.com/blog/spark-use-case-popular-movie-analysis/ and https://github.com/ragnar-lothbrok/spark-demo/blob/master/src/main/java/com/spark/sql/BasketMarketAnalysis.java You will get some idea.